# How can I make Apache work on port 80? MAMP home page not found

Tags: apache, ip

I am developing a Wordpress site on my Mac. I installed MAMP with default ports (Apache on port 8888). Everything was working fine, and my boss could view my progress over our LAN. Now we need someone who works offsite to provide feedback, and so I was given a static IP address. When we accessed that IP from the coffee shop across the street, all we could see was the default Mac homepage ("It works!") instead of the Wordpress site.

I decided that port 8888 for Apache and port 8889 for MySQL were incorrect for external access, so I moved them to 80 and 3306, respectively. It took me all day reviewing forums to be able to access the wordpress site from my local host, but now I can't access the MAMP home page. I get a 404.

When Apache was on port 8888, I would click on the MAMP button, 'Open WebStart page' and I would see MAMP at the address `http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English`. Now, however, I click the button, and a webpage attempts to access `http://localhost:10/MAMP/?language=English`. Where did the `:10` come from? Earlier today, I could remove the port 10 and access the MAMP homepage. Now, after getting access to the wordpress site again, removing port 10 doesn't help. The message the browser gives me is: `The requested URL /MAMP/ was not found on this server.`

One of the things I did to be able to view the wordpress site on my localhost again was to move all the wordpress files from Applications/MAMP/htdocs to /Library/Webserver/Documents/Wordpress. Of course, I changed this setting in the MAMP preferences.

Has anybody ever fixed this sort of issue? Or was my assumption wrong, the assumption that external IP access would not work on port 8888?

Comment: Hi Scott, welcome to WPSE. Unfortunately we're not going to be able to help much on this here because it's a server configuration issue rather than a Wordpress issue. Have a look at http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-traffic - Stack Overflow, Server Fault and maybe even Ask Different might be able to help with your question, but make sure you read their help first to check if your question is on-topic for the site you choose.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add an virtual host that points to your site... it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mywordpress-site
    ServerName mywordpress-site
</VirtualHost>
```

Document root is the path to your site.
ServerName is the url to ur site (you need to add "mywordpress-site" to your /etc/hosts file)

Follow these steps [here](http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php):